# Buscar entre 2 fechas datetime MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo esta tabla de registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi campo fecha_reg es tipo datetime, al buscar un registro de mes en especifico normalmente uso fecha_reg="año-mes-dia" y normal me muestra, el problema es al buscar entre un rango de fecha
estoy usando esto:

```
WHERE R.fecha_reg BETWEEN CAST('2021-04-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2021-04-04' AS DATE)
```

Me muestra solo los registros desde 2021-04-01 hasta 2021-04-03 es decir hasta 1 dia antes

Comment: es una base de datos ya estructurada y ahy un sistema que funciona en base a este modelo el cambiar el campo no podria ser una opcion :(

Comment: podrias poner tu respuesta porfavor ? seria de mucha ayuda

Comment: lo prove y no funcionó amigo, sigue sin encontrarme registros

Comment: Mmmm el problema es el orden en que estás poniendo las fechas, tienes que poner primero la más reciente y luego la más antigua, al hacerlo al revés no la encuentra. Prueba así: **`...   WHERE R.fecha_reg BETWEEN CAST('2021-04-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2021-04-12' AS DATE)`**

Comment: @A.Cedano de acuerdo con lo que expones sería primero la mas antigua y luego la mas reciente ¿no?

Comment: si si tienen razon fue un error mio, funciona el codigo pero me si pongo la segunda fecha, me muestra solo hasta un dia antes, por ejemplo si pongo **...   WHERE R.fecha_reg BETWEEN CAST('2021-04-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2021-04-12' AS DATE)** me muestra solo desde 2021-04-01 hasta 2021-04-11

Comment: Pero, ¿tienes datos el día 12 de abril? Si te sale hasta el 11 es porque seguramente no hay datos el 12 de abril. Acabo de probarlo y funciona.

Comment: @BetaM sí, era el revés, me lié en la explicación. Es, la fecha más vieja antes del `AND` y la más reciente después del `AND`.  En suma `BETWEEN` funciona como un *menor o igual que Y mayor o igual que*

Comment: La respuesta fue sencilla **WHERE R.fecha_reg BETWEEN '2021-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-04-02 23:59:59'** gracias por su colaboracion e intencion de ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Si leemos el MR, [dice lo siguiente sobre `BETWEEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between):

#### `expr BETWEEN min AND max`

> If expr is greater than or equal to min and expr is less than or equal
> to max, BETWEEN returns 1, otherwise it returns 0. This is equivalent
> to the expression (min <= expr AND expr <= max) if all the arguments
> are of the same type. Otherwise type conversion takes place according
> to the rules described in Section 12.3, “Type Conversion in Expression
> Evaluation”, but applied to all the three arguments.

---

#### `expr BETWEEN min AND max`

> Si `expr` es mayor o igual que `min` y `expr` es menor o igual que
> `max`, `BETWEEN` devuelve 1, de lo contrario devuelve 0. Esto es
> equivalente a la expresión (`min <= expr AND expr <= max`) si todos
> los argumentos son del mismo tipo. De lo contrario, la conversión de
> tipos se lleva a cabo de acuerdo con las reglas descritas en la
> Sección 12.3, [“Conversión de tipos en la evaluación de
> expresiones”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html), pero se aplican a los tres argumentos.

En suma, **tienes que poner la fecha más antigua antes del AND y luego del AND la más reciente**, si lo pones al revés, como es lógico, no encontrará fechas entre 12 de abril y el 1 de abril.

Para evitar que excluya las fechas del último criterio, puedes aplicar `DATE()` a la columna con la que quieres comparar.

Así debería funciona, salvo otros errores:

```
...   WHERE DATE(R.fecha_reg) BETWEEN CAST('2021-04-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2021-04-12' AS DATE)
```

Comment: funciona para las fechas desde pero no para las fechas hasta, es decir si pongo entre 2021-04-01 hasta 2021-04-03 me muestra los registros desde 2021-04-01 hasta 2021-04-02 es decir no me considera el 03 si no solo hasta el 02

Comment: @IntruzO pero mi pregunta es: ¿hay registros con fecha del `2021-04-03`?. Yo he probado la consulta en un fiddle y funciona perfectamente. Si no muestra del día 3 es porque quizá no tienes registros ese día. O, puede haber algún JOIN en la consulta que por algún motivo no encuentre esa fecha en caso de existir. Si hay fechas del día 3 y no las muestra edita la pregunta y pon tu consulta completa para revisarla.

Comment: El problema es que tu fecha es DATETIME y el DATE se convierte en DATETIME con hora 0. 

O sea que tu límite MAX es 2021-04-03 00:00:00 por lo que cualquier registro que sea superior no aparece. Ejemplo: 2021-04-03 00:00:01 ya no es menor o igual y no es devuelto.

Cuando filtras por DATETIME es mejor usar rangos de fechas: WHERE R.fecha_reg >= 2021-04-01 AND R.fecha_reg < 2021-04-04 (Importante notar que el límite superior es el día siguiente a las 0 hs y el comparador es estrictamente menor que).
Esto sería desde 2021-04-01 00:00:00 hasta justo antes del 2021-04-04 00:00:00 hs.

Comment: La respuesta fue sencilla **WHERE R.fecha_reg BETWEEN '2021-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-04-02 23:59:59'** gracias por su colaboracion e intencion de ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que tu campo no es date, es datetime, por lo que no tomara ese dia como un valor correcto porque al menos si se pasa un minuto no entra dentro de tu rango, lo que podrias hacer es hacer la conversion al campo de esa manera tomara su valor como date, quedaria asi:

```
WHERE DATE(R.fecha_reg) BETWEEN CAST('2021-04-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2021-04-04' AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es por el tipo de datos. si no indicas la hora, el sistema toma como referencia esa fecha  2021-04-04 a las 00:00 osea al inicio de ese dia. 2021-04-04 00:01 ya queda fuera de ese rango.

Para solucionarlo puedes sumarle un dia a la fecha final.

Comment: La respuesta fue sencilla **WHERE R.fecha_reg BETWEEN '2021-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-04-02 23:59:59'** gracias por su colaboracion e intencion de ayudar.

Comment: prueba con BETWEEN CAST('2021-04-01' AS DATE) AND ( CAST('2021-04-04' AS DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY )

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta fue sencilla

```
WHERE R.fecha_reg BETWEEN '2021-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-04-02 23:59:59'
```

espero les sirva a alguno y gracias por su colaboracion e intencion de ayudar.

Comment: Te recuerdo que el problema principal no era este, sino que tenías los criterios invertidos. Revisa mi respuesta editada, he sugerido una solución para evitar el problema de que no incluye el último día. Por otra parte, el MR recomienda que se use CAST en las consultas BETWEEN.

Comment: no fue los criterios invertidos fue un error de tipeo, era principalmente como dice el titulo **Buscar entre 2 fechas datetime MYSQL PHP**